# WCF Unable to Load Custom Behavior Extension From Strongly Named Assembly

Tags: .net, wcf, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

i have a custom behavior extension which i'm using in my client side app.config

```
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="consoleMessageTracing" type="Extensions.ConsoleMessageTracingElement, Extensions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
```

this works great, but if i move my custom behavior code into a project which is strongly named, and update the behavior like below:

```
    <add name="consoleMessageTracing" type="Common.WcfExtensions.ConsoleMessageTracingElement, Common.WcfExtensions, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f7ac309eefe2c404" />
```

i get the following error:

> SetUp : System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException : The type
>   'Common.WcfExtensions.ConsoleMessageTracingElement,
>   Common.WcfExtensions, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=f7ac309eefe2c404' registered for extension
>   'consoleMessageTracing' could not be loaded.

can anyone help explain what i'm doing wrong? the token key is correct and the version of the assembly is correct.

UPDATE:
if i use the WCF configuration editor, i get the same message.  some reason its unable to read the DLL, the Common.DLL is in the bin directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so where do you deploy the strongly named assembly to? If it is in the GAC on the machine then it should find it there. If it is under your appbase then the first assembly ir finds with a matching DLL name (Common.WcfExtensions.dll) will be examined and if you happen to have one lying around that does not have the strong name then it will fail the load.

You could try using FusLogVw.exe to see what happens when it attempts to load the assembly - there's a guide to using it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28VS.71%29.aspx)

I've also found behavior extensions to be very sensitive to things like spaces in the name. Try removing and adding the spaces in various combinations

Comment: ok, so to give you my scenario - i've created a unit test with a service reference to the local WCF service.  i've updated my client config to use my extension (as above).
my test project has reference to the SN assembly - this causes the error.  if i reference the none-SN assembly, it works.  so i can see the only difference is strongly named assembly.

Comment: ok - its not strongly naming which is causing the issue, i signed my working assembly - got an error, added the SN key and it worked.. must be something else

Comment: I'd try fuslogvw.exe to see if there's an assembly binding failure