# WCF behavior extension could not be loaded

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, cors

I'm currently getting to know SOAP and I've created a simple WCF project with a couple of methods which I wanted to test through HTMl/JS.

I ran into a CORS-issue and tried to enable CORS using [this resource](https://enable-cors.org/server_wcf.html) but I've still got an issue loading the behaviorextension.

The behaviorextensionelement I added could first not be recognized in the Web.config, I fixed this by implementing [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43662810/20228825) but when launching the service I still get the `System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: The type 'AttemptAtSOAP.EnableCrossOriginResourceSharingBehavior, AttemptAtSOAP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null ' registered for extension 'crossOriginResourceSharingBehavior' could not be loaded.`

I believe my mistake is within the "type"-field here but I'm not sure what it should be

```
<extensions>
          <behaviorExtensions>
              <!--error seems to be within the "type"-field-->
              <add name="crossOriginResourceSharingBehavior" type="AttemptAtSOAP.EnableCrossOriginResourceSharingBehavior, AttemptAtSOAP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          </behaviorExtensions>
      </extensions>
```

The layout of my project is currently this:

[image: project layout]

I noticed the [suggestion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787299/wcf-error-extension-could-not-be-loaded) mentioned setting the type to the reference of your DLL, but I don't have one so that might be a first mistake...

Let me know if I need to provide some more info or if you have a clue, cheers!

Comment: You may refer to [the case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759977/wcf-unable-to-load-custom-behavior-extension-from-strongly-named-assembly) for more help.

Comment: @Jiayao thanks for the suggestion, however as I don't have a DLL there's no logs showing anything happening. I have however abandoned the idea of creating a WCF service and instead will make one in .NET core, but for future reference, this does not solve my problem.